# HTTP status code 4xx vs 5xx

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I am creating a REST API and find it difficult to choose the right HTTP status code to return in some cases.

Let's say I expect a certain value, and when it is not present I cannot perform a certain task and return an error. Because of the missing value the server cannot handle the request, but it was the client who sent it, wellformed but incomplete, in. Would it be best to return a `4xx` or a `5xx` error?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Stick to the standards!

The decision of which HTTP status code you will send to the client is up to you but you *really should stick to the standards*. The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) is the current reference for content and semantics of the HTTP/1.1 protocol. It's a must read when creating an API on the top of the HTTP protocol.

### `4xx` vs `5xx` status codes

Use `4xx` status codes for client errors and `5xx` status codes for server errors:

> [**6.5.  Client Error 4xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)
>
> The `4xx` (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
> seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.  These status codes are applicable to any request method.
> User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

> [**6.6.  Server Error 5xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6)
>
> The `5xx` (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server
> is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the
> requested method.  Except when responding to a `HEAD` request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.  A user agent SHOULD display any included representation
> to the user.  These response codes are applicable to any request
> method.

### Which status code you should use

For the situation you mentioned in your question, you could use `400` or maybe `422` (from WebDAV, a HTTP extension):

> [**6.5.1.  400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

> [**11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415`(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Along with the status code, ensure you send a representation (such as JSON or XML) containing an explanation of the error situation in the response payload. Have a look at the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), it describes a stardard for problem details for HTTP APIs.

### A great decision chart

For more details, check this [decision chart](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) from Racksburg:

The status codes are grouped into three rough categories:

[image: HTTP status codes categories]

Start here:

[image: HTTP status codes]

Choosing `2xx` and `3xx` status codes:

[image: HTTP 2xx and 3xx status codes]

Choosing `4xx` status codes:

[image: HTTP 4xx status codes]

Choosing `5xx` status codes:

[image: HTTP 5xx status codes]

Comment: For 2xx and 3xx responses, for the question "Was the location created for the request", i think that a 303 can be returned if the location was created for the request, ie with a POST.  303 should direct the client that the location was created, and also provide a Location response header to where to GET it.  That seems to contradict the diagram: it needs an extra bubble for the "Yes" branch instead of this "No" i believe.  Happy to elaborate.

Comment: Wow. Amazing Compilation. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for putting all this together in one place!

Comment: That last diamond, "Do you feel bad your code can't handle the request?", makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: I finally realized why that last diamond in the 5xx diagram doesn't make sense to me.  It's because it's backwards!  "Do you feel bad your code can't handle the request?"  If **no**, you don't feel bad, then you return a 501 Not Implemented.  If **yes**, you do feel bad, then you regard it as an error, and you return 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: (Since making that previous comment, I edited to fix the image.)

Answer (score 2):

It is totally upto you that what response you want to send to client.

But while sending a response you must be aware that it should be generic and clear about the incident which caused the request to fail.

Designing **API** is like desiging an agreement between the client and server. 
Server has to serve to client until that agreement or API specification is followed. It should clearly indicate in Api specification docs.

In your above case since server was accepting certain values with the request param and client did not sent it, it was fault of client since client did not agreed to api specification provided ahead of sending request.

In this case server should return 
**HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST** which is equal to **400** in code.

**Tip:**
I would suggest you should not just return error code but also provide some error message with the response if any error occurs.

e.g

`response : { errorCode:4xx, errorMessage:"Some thing went wrong"}`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR [Stick to standards!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639949/625332), but there are scenarios where it could be relaxed.

I think 4xx vs 5xx depends on the server relationship with the client. I agree with the accepted answer if you are building a public API or you are not sure how the API will be consumed. In fact I think it should be a default choice when building APIs.

However there is certain cost associated with differentiating between 4xx and 5xx (400 and 500 to be specific). And in some cases the cost may not be justified. Lets say you are building an API and you have complete control over the client. Both API and the client belong to the same app and they both will be released together ([Bounded Context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) in DDD lingo). Client and API are essentially a single app with HTTP used as a glue. Basically we are not using the API to be decoupled from the client. This often happens when building something like [Backend For Frontend](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/). In terms of layering you may have following:

- Frontend (aware of business rules)
- API/BFF(?)
- Domain model or downstream service (enforces business
  rules)

Now when building API in this scenario, you may want to take a shortcut and just pass on frontend requests downstream with minimal translation. Basically keep the API layer thin. The model will enforce business rules anyway (by throwing an exception for example). These types of crashes automatically get converted to 500 error by the web framework. The end result is that you may not return 'proper' 400 or 412 status code to client and will return 500 instead, which is incorrect from HTTP standpoint. But guess what. Your client does not care and does not differentiate between 400 and 500 - it treats them the same. Both are considered to be bugs in 'the app'. There may special treatment for 503s on the client side, but I think it is a separate consideration.

```
// internal api with a tightly coupled consumer (think SPA)

public Response BuyLifeInsurance(Request request) {

    // how much upstream and downstream logic do you want to
    // duplicate here knowing that _downstream still enforces
    // all the rules and will throw on violation? And client
    // also knows about the rules and the violation means a bug.
    // Why think about 400 vs 412 semantics? Who cares if it
    // is 400 or 500 if both are treated as bugs that should be
    // fixed by _your_ team (either on client or server)? You 
    // should care about life insurance and not http purity anyway :)

    // why not let the call below crash and return 500 and figure
    // out where the bug is based on logs?

    _downstream.BuyLifeInurance(
        new Age(request.age),       
        new Amount(request.amount));
}
```

Basically in certain cases it may be wasteful to duplicate business logic that is already implemented on the client and enforced in the downstream model. So the API layer may just as well stay thin at the expense of theoretical pureness. I'd call this scenario a Weak API™. A useful though experiment - how much focus would you put on being compliant with protocol idioms if it was not HTTP? What if this was not an API but a simple internal library? IMHO it only pays if you are using API to be decoupled from client (which is majority of cases, but there are exceptions which I outlined above).

Answer (score 0):

I find that knowing the error details by adding **error: error.detail** will return a response that helps guide me on what error code to send. In the below code, the response (using Postman) fingered the client's or user's bad request. This made error code 400 appropriate.

Note, that putting any status code, say 500, will not make a difference since it's just an assumption. The error detail will however point you to the right way to go.

if (error) {

```
    return res.status(400).send({
      type: error.name,
      status: "Failure",
      error: error.detail,
      message: "Please check the error message and try again!"
    });
   }
```

[image: Code block on vscode and the output on Postman]